# Android WebView loads page in 2.3 but not 4.0

Tags: android, webview

My WebView works perfectly in Android 2.3 but on my Nexus S with 4.0 the pages don't get loaded properly anymore. The background color loads but nothing else.

What has changed with 4.0?

Thankful or any help I can get!

My WebView Code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){                        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    webView.clearCache(true);
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(Home.this, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                        // Hide/Show loading animation
        }

        @Override
        public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String 
            super.onConsoleMessage(message, lineNumber, sourceID);
        }
    });

    // SETUP WEBVIEW
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.scrollBy(0, 0);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); 
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0x333333);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.loadUrl(urlButton1);

    // Test
    webView.clearSslPreferences();
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Comment: In the topmost middle there is a small square that looks like parts of the page.. really strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `webView.setInitialScale(1);`
It doesn't work on ICS

Comment: I accepted the answer since this did in fact help in one case. In another it does not however. Oh and yeah sorry for the late accept :D